# Heap Corruption Detected C++ Custom Vector

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hey I am rehashing through a few old projects in a class I took and as I'm redoing this project I keep getting this error when my clear() function is called in the driver,

Heap Corruption Detected: after Normal block (#142)
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after the end of the HEAP buffer

Here is my custom Vector class

```
#include "MyVector.h"

//insert header files
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//setup access to necessary libraries
using namespace std;

MyVector::MyVector()
{
    // initialize member data
    size = 0;
    capacity = 2;

    //initialize new array
    classArray = new int[capacity];
}

MyVector::MyVector(int maxCapacity)
{
    // initialize member data
    size = 0;
    capacity = maxCapacity;

    // initialize new array
    classArray = new int[capacity];
}

MyVector::~MyVector()
{
    if (classArray != NULL)
    {
        delete [] classArray;
        classArray = NULL;
    }
}

int MyVector::getSize()
{
    return size;
}

int MyVector::getCapacity()
{
    return capacity;
}

void MyVector::clear()
{
    // delete the array
    delete[] classArray;

    // reinitialize the array
    capacity = 2;
    size = 0;

    classArray = new int[capacity];
}

void MyVector::push_back(int n)
{
    if (size > capacity)
    {
        // setup the special case of an array with 0 elements
        if (size == 0)
        {
            clear();
        }
        else
        {
            // declare a temporary pointer and allocate a new array
            capacity = capacity * 2;
            int* tempArray = new int[capacity];

            // copy the values from the old array to the temporary array
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                tempArray[i] = classArray[i];
            }

            // call the destructor
            delete[] classArray;

            // assign the classArray pointer to the new array
            classArray = tempArray;
        }
    }

    // pushback a new value to the array
    classArray[size] = n;

    // increment size
    size++;
}

int MyVector::at(int n)
{
    // check if n is within the bounds of the array
    if (n >= size)
    {
        throw n;
    }

    // if not return the value of the index requested
    else
    {
        return classArray[n];
    }
}
```

and here is my driver code,

```
//insert header files
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyVector.h"

//setup access to necessary libraries
using namespace std;

//declare constants
#pragma region Constants
const int TEST_VALUE1 = 21;
const int TEST_VALUE2 = 31;
const int TEST_VALUE3 = 41;

const int MAX = 12;
#pragma endregion

int main()
{
    // Create a default vector 
    MyVector sam;

    // push some data into sam
    cout << "\nPushing three values into sam";
    sam.push_back(TEST_VALUE1);
    sam.push_back(TEST_VALUE2);
    sam.push_back(TEST_VALUE3);

    cout << "\nThe values in sam are: ";

    // test for out of bounds condition here
    // and test exception 
    for (int i = 0; i < sam.getSize() + 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << sam.at(i) << " ";
        }
        catch (int badIndex)
        {
            cout << "\nOut of bounds at index " << badIndex << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n--------------\n";

    // clear sam and display its size and capacity
    sam.clear(); //********ERROR BEING THROWN HERE*********
    cout << "\nsam has been cleared.";
    cout << "\nSam's size is now " << sam.getSize();
    cout << "\nSam's capacity is now " << sam.getCapacity() << endl;
    cout << "---------------\n";

    // Push 12 values into the vector - it should grow
    cout << "\nPush 12 values into sam.";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        sam.push_back(i);

    cout << "\nSam's size is now " << sam.getSize();
    cout << "\nSam's capcacity is now " << sam.getCapacity() << endl;
    cout << "---------------\n";

    cout << "\nTest to see if contents are correct...";
    // display the values in the vector
    for (int i = 0; i < sam.getSize(); i++)
    {

        cout << sam.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n--------------\n";

    cout << "\n\nTest Complete...";

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I've looked back and forth at my old project several times and I can't see why I am getting this error when I am trying to delete something. I mean it sounds like that usually happens when I am trying to allocate something that can't be allocated but not deleted?

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please browse "C++ Rule of 3"

Comment: `Hey I am rehashing through a few old projects in a class I took`  Try this simple, 2 line program: `int main() { myVector sam; myVector sam2(sam); }`  I've just broken your class.

Comment: @tokyo0709 Your `clear` function should just make the size = 0.  It doesn't need to deallocate memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why don't I need to deallocate memory? Is the destructor just there and automatically called when the program exits the main block then?

Comment: @tokyo0709  Look at your code carefully.  Why do you need to deallocate memory every time that `clear` is called?  You have the `size` and `capacity` members.  If `size` is 0 and `capacity` is 100, then so be it.   You won't really allocate until `size` is >= `capacity`.  You save yourself a useless call to deallocation and allocation again, and defer this until `size` is indeed >= `capacity`.  Of course the destructor has to truly deallocate the memory, but that is different than `clear`.

Comment: @tokyo0709 To summarize, deallocating memory each time `clear` is called defeats your whole purpose of having a `capacity` member.  The only thing you need is *logically* set the current number of elements to 0, and you do that by simply setting the `size` member to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `push_back` code can be reduced to:

```
if (size > capacity)
{
    // resize
}
classArray[size] = n;
size++;
```

But note that you start with `size == 0` and `capacity == 2`, then have three calls to `push_back`. On the third one, `size == 2` and `capacity == 2`. `size > capacity` is still `false`, so you'll write into `classArray[2]` (without having resized) which is uninitialized memory. This is undefined behavior.

You want to check `size >= capacity` to resize.

Note that there's another serious problem with your class: you failed to write a copy constructor, so if you copied it, both copies would attempt to deallocate the same memory. See Rule of Three (updated in C++11 to Rule of Five).

Comment: Oh gosh I had that set that way earlier and then for some reason I thought it had to be just,

size >= capacity

Thanks! By the way, can I just call the destructor and default constructor in my clear function rather than repeating code or is this not allowed?

Comment: @tokyo0709 No it's not.